# Square sq-payment-form Money amount not populating

Tags: square-connect

the example form(C#), sq-payment-form hard codes the amount to charge as 
Money amount = new Money(100, Money.CurrencyEnum.USD); I believe I need to change the 100 to reference the charge value in the form. however, I can't find any information on how to accomplish.

I have added a field to the form id "tc"

```
  <div class="sq-field">
      <label class="sq-label sq-field--in-wrapper">Total Charge</label>
      <input class="sq-field" type="text" id="tc" />
      <div id="sq-amount"></div>
  </div>
```

and put an alert in the .js file to display tc.value
i see the value in the alert but in the onpost method i cannot seem to reference the field using response.form("tc")
I have tired referencing both

```
string tcharge = Request.Form["sq-amount"].;
string tcharge = Request.Form["tc"]();
```

to no avail..... all the examples on the square site i have found hard code the charge amount.  one of the examples on the Square site actually has a comment as follows;
"// Monetary amounts are specified in the smallest unit of the applicable currency.
            // This amount is in cents. It's also hard-coded for $1.00,
            // which isn't very useful.

```
        Money amount = new Money(100, Money.CurrencyEnum.USD);"
```

what am I missing

both the form objects are null so the transaction fails.  I am fairly new to C# and would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: after more digging A little more clarification.....
I have in the form

     <div class="sq-field sq-field--in-wrapper">
              <label class="sq-label">Total Charge</label>
              <div id="sq-totalcharge">2000</div>
          </div>

in the .js

    ,
      totalcharge: {
         elementId: 'sq-totalcharge'
      },

My question is with what do I replace the hard-coded 100 in (Payment-Process.cshtml.cs) the following line of code to pass the total charge amount?
 

    Money amount = new Money(**100**, Money.CurrencyEnum.USD);

TIA

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting the customer to be able to enter a value and pass it to your backend to charge, you would just need to implement another form field (like the hidden card nonce). For example:

```
<input type="text" name="sq-amount">
```

When the form is submitted, you would be able to retrieve the value that was entered like you have above (you would probably want to add in some checks to ensure it's a valid amount etc):

```
string tcharge = Request.Form["sq-amount"].;
...
Money amount = new Money(Int32.Parse(tcharge), Money.CurrencyEnum.USD);"
```